# saving user field type custom field - Failed to set unsafe attribute

Tags: custom-field

I have tried to save a custom field of "user field" type which resulted in this error.

> "Failed to set unsafe attribute"

code:

```
$order->setAttributes(array(
    'operatorUid' => Craft::$app->user->id
));
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can you let me know how to save a custom userType field to an order?

Answer (score 3):

In order to set field values there is `setFieldValue` function

```
$element->setFieldValue('fieldHandle', [Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->id]);
```

All relation fields only accept the values as an array `[1]` rather than integer `1`

Comment: Thank you, your comments helped me but in Craft 3, I can now just do this.   $order->"fieldname" = [Craft::$app->user->id];

Comment: No you can't. This may work in one specific scenario but it's highly suggested not to do this. You can only do this with `field:handle` otherwise the value won't be normalized

Comment: sure, will keep an eye on further use-cases. Thank you